# PostgreSQL Table or Column names cAse

Tags: postgresql

Whenever a execute a query such as :

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (myColumn INTEGER);
```

PostgreSQL automatically converts the Table and Column names to lowercase like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (mycolumn INTEGER);
```

Is there any way to change the source code of PostgreSQL to avoid this automatic change?

I *know the Double Quote method*... But...

The Application I'm using is very large. So it is very difficult to change every occurrence of the query. Instead, I would like to change the source code of PostgreSQL which is found on GitHub.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: you can only prevent them from happening if you use those evil quoted identifiers. But why do you want to do that?

Comment: If you **never** use double quotes you don't have a problem.

Comment: If I don't use double quotes, then everything gets's converted to lower case. That is what I'm trying to say from the beginning -_-

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE "myTable" ("myColumn" INTEGER);
```

Comment: Yes, this works but it'd be a very tedious task to change each and every occurrence of the query in the whole project. I have a very short time period to complete the project.

Comment: SQL has **not** been designed to accomodate CamelCase notation for identifiers. Programs were written with single case letters, and the common convention was to use only  `compound_identifiers_as_words_separated_by_underscore`.